# FaceBook Video sharing

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have a web application and want to post video, messages and images to social platform using only site URL.

I added image and message description meta tags into HTML Head so that Facebook crawls image and description information.

```
<meta property="og:image" content=image_url>
<meta property="og:description" content="Test">
```

But video sharing meta tags are not working.

```
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0DPdy98e4c">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0DPdy98e4c">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="800">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="600">
```

Does anyone have an idea about sharing video in Open Graph Facebook meta tag?

Comment: Because you have to specify URLs that points to videos. Your URL points to a HTML page which contains a video. Also type should not be Flash. Flash is dead.

Comment: WizKid, thanks for your response.
<meta property="og:url" content=youtube_link>
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4"> is workig?

Comment: Can you provide me sample web site for video sharing?

Comment: You need to include a link to an mp4 files. Your Youtube links goes to a HTML page. Pretty sure Youtube is not giving you mp4 links because they want you to go to Youtube to watch the videos

Comment: Even if you specify a valid video via meta tags, there is little chance Facebook will still display this as a video playable inline in the feed - they have reduced the amount of posts displayed that way massively.

Comment: CBroe, good feedback!, 
Is there any other way to share video outside of facebook web site?